# Discriminated union not working when narrowing after array access

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Given these two types:

```
type Prospect = {
    name: string;
}

type Client = {
    name: string;
    account: string;
}
```

Let's create a union where `kind` acts as the discriminator:

```
type Union = 
| {kind: "prospect", persons: Prospect[]} 
| {kind: "client", persons: Client[]};

const {persons, kind} = {} as Union
```

Type narrowing works as expected when accessing `persons`.

```
if (kind === "client") {
    persons.map(person => { // person: Client
        person.account // All good
    })
}
```

It, however, fails to work after accessing an individual element from `persons`.

```
const person = persons[0]
if (kind === "client") { // person: Prospect | Client
    person.account // Error
}
```

How can I achieve type narrowing **after** I have already accessed an array? I could add a `kind` field to `Prospect` and `Client` but that seems redundant given that persons is always an array of `Prospect` or `Client` and not a mix of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move person access inside type guard:

```js
if (kind === "client") { // person: Prospect | Client
    const person = persons[0]
    person.account // Ok
}
```

In your case of

```js
const person = persons[0]
if (kind === "client") { // person: Prospect | Client
    person.account // Error
}
```

Typescript cannot guess that person/persons[0] didn't mutate and change type between assignment and type guard, so it cannot safely narrow type.